# Login to wordpress automatcally

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

i want to gain access to this website with valid username and password using php or http requests

https://oldmanandgoodliar.pw/login/

is there anyway to do so ? filling the forms and login automatically

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your first line in function.php file of your theme or plugin

```
if( isset($_GET['username']) and $_GET['pass'] ) {
$user = get_user_by('login', $_GET['username']);

if ( $user && wp_check_password( $_GET['pass'], $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login);

    wp_redirect( admin_url() );
    exit;
}

wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit;}
```

After doing this login using:
**[www.yoursite.com/wp-admin?username=yourusername&pass=yourpassword](http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin?username=yourusername&pass=yourpassword)**

Comment: the site is not mine i just have an account to access the main site i dont have a plugin . i just want to autmate login and access to main site with script

Comment: You can upload a script to the same domain and use cURL but that is not recommended. You can not create a script from another domain as WP needs some cookie to setup and you are not allowed to setup cookie from other domains. So the only way to make it work is to have an admin account and either add the above function for an easy login or create a script php file using curl on the same domain to autologin ... the simple way is to just to use the save password function of your browser :)